# How can "npm install <module>" be used to develop pages intended for browsers?

Tags: javascript, browser, npm, installation

When adding a resource to a page running in a browser I either link to the file (locally, served by the web server, or on a CDN)

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://somecdn.com/mycssresource.min.css">
<script src="alocalscript.js"></script>
```

or use webpack which ultimately bundles `npm` installed modules into one `bundle.js`, served by my web server.

When reading documentations of frameworks I often see (recently in [Bulma](https://bulma.io/documentation/overview/start/)) the recommended way to install the framework as

```
npm install <framework>
```

I understand the usage for Node.js programs (where everything runs locally on the server, so the sources of the framework have their place there) but for browser-based dev, the files installed by `npm install` which reside in `node_modules` must ultimately make their way to the browser where the code actually runs.

**Is the recommendation (or first choice) to install a framework via `npm install` applicable for code intended for browsers, or is it only for Node.js or webpack (or similar bundlers) usage?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally I prefer to install via npm install and then use a relative URL like `/node_modules/.../filename.css` for example.

I also know some people prefer to copy the css/js of the package and serve them from their own directory like `/assets/css/...` or `/assets/js/..`. This way they can edit/add to the original framework if they wanted and keep the changes since they commit them in git.

Another very popular option is CDN, and many people recommend that for a big advantage of caching, especially if the user had already downloaded that file because it was used in another website they visited, it will be faster for them to load your app/website since they have those files cached locally in their browser and don't have to re-download.

Comment: In your first case, you need to expose the whole `node_modules` directory, this is not that different from your second case. Both are addressed in the beginning of my question. The CDN part is absolutely correct - and this is why using a well-known CDN cas speed things up. Still I do not see why `npm install` would be useful, except as a way to bring the files locally (similar to saving the URL locally), and then expose them with the rest of the code.

Comment: @WoJ If I understood you correct, no, just as in Node.js, `npm install` has no other use than to fetch the packages and save them locally so you don't have to include them every time you want to deploy (zipping thousands of files can sometimes take a while). That plus always using the same version to avoid any problems with incompatible packages when one of them updates. But you get that with CDN anyways since the version is in the URL.

Comment: @WoJ Also when using npm it's very easy to update the packages rather than manually searching for new versions on CDN.